# Android - How to get list of available aperatures

Tags: android, camera

New to Android. Trying to understand how to get the list of available apertures. The code below does not work as expected. Could someone please explain how I can extract the list from this property? Using camera 2 api.

```
apertures = CameraCharacteristics.LENS_INFO_AVAILABLE_APERTURES;
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `getCameraCharacteristics("camerayouwant").get()` to get the characters.

```
float[] aperatures = CameraManager.getCameraCharacteristics("camerayouwant").get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_INFO_AVAILABLE_APERTURES);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `aperatures = CameraManager.getCameraCharacteristics("camerayouwant").get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_INFO_AVAILABLE_APERTURES);`

Comment: Please add brief explanation to your answer.